# White outline for a text object

Tags: modeling

How do a i make the most simple white outline for a text mesh? I am exporting a 3D text to a graphic editor as a PNG. The background and the mesh are the same color so i need a white outline. Is there a super easy way?
Render engine is Cycles.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### The object is polygon geometry or rendered already

In a 2D postprocessing step, you can use a dilate node on the alpha channel. This could also be done in any image editing/compositing software.

[image]

### The object is a 3D text

1. Duplicate the text object.
2. Change the color of the duplicate.
3. Decrease the texts **extrude** property and increase its **bevel** and **offset** properties.

[image]

Comment: The second step was perfect! Thank you! (i feel really dumb - it's so easy)

Comment: Can I give material to the extruded part?

Comment: @Evripidis Yes.