# How to make 3d text font with very thick stroke in blender 2.9

Tags: workflow, text-object

I'm still beginner in blender and i was told to make a 3d font in blender, but it must have a very thick stroke.

**This is the example**
[image]

I have tried to edit the offset font, adding object modifier (like boolean and solidify) but still can't.

are there any tips to achieve this result? Thank you.

Comment: Does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/131385/white-outline-for-a-text-object) help?

Comment: for that I have tried it too by adding the offset text font. but when the font offset is too big, the text becomes broken and weird.

Comment: if you don't need a perfect topology you can convert your font to object, X > Limited DIssolve to simplify its topology, duplicate it and fatten the duplicate with Alt S?

Comment: I'll try later, because right now my laptop is being borrowed by someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender doesn't have great curve edit tools, hence try to make this in a different app, like an Inkscape.

I don't want to cover how to create this effect, but it is relatively simple. Why don't you watch a tutorial? For example:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4Ib3xr6lHY&ab_channel=NatashaSchumacher

After creating the vector drawing, you can import SVG file in Blender and use it as curve objects.

Comment: That might be a good idea, I'll try that later. thank you